# Change Symfony form action once the request has been handled

Tags: php, symfony

I got a Symfony 2 form that has been created using createForm. Once the form has been validated I need to modify the action I initially set. Is this possible?

```
$formData = $this->loadData($id);

// Form builder
$form = $this->createForm(new ComposeForm(), $formData, [
    'action' => $$this->generateUrl('defaultAction')
]);

// Processing form
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();

    $myVar = $form->get('myVar')->isClicked();
    if ($myVar) {
        // Can I change the form action here??
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do so? A form will be handled by one action normally.

Comment: Got two submit buttons that trigger different actions. I would like to submit the form via POST in both cases so redirections do not seem a option.

Comment: Could you explain in detail what you want to do in your question? I'm guessing that you're on a wrong approach to your goal, but I can't tell what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was interested in knowing if what I posted was possible or not as I could not find how to do it anywhere. Probably, as you pointed, as it is not a good idea to solve the problem this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straight forward in a controller :

```
if ($myVar) {
        $form->setAction($this->generateUrl('target_route'))
    }
```

But I dont see the point of doing so.

Comment: Tried that before, I got: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\Form::setAction()

Comment: what does $this->createForm() does?

Comment: The method is included on the Controller class, basically it creates a form instance; http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_createForm. Why setAction doesn't work, I'm not sure about it.